# Rails prepend twice to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails 4.2. I have the following:

```
field = ["can't be blank", "is invalid"]

def error_message_for(field)
  if field.present?
    if field.size > 1
      field.last.prepend("and/or ")
    end
    field.join(", ")
  end
end

error_message_for(field)
```

I expect the output to be `can't be blank, and/or is invalid`, but it's `can't be blank, and/or and/or is invalid` instead. You see `and/or` appears twice.

What is wrong?

Comment: What’s wrong with `field.join(" and/or ")`?!

Comment: @mudasobwa: presumably it's so you can have a sentence like "a, b and/or c". See my answer on the use of `to_sentence`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks okay to me. Are you sure you aren't running an old cached version (try restarting rails server), or have any odd monkey-patches in place?

That said, I think what you're trying to achieve is doable in an easier way in Rails: have a look at [to_sentence](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_sentence).

This can simplify to:

```
field.to_sentence(last_word_connector: ' and/or ')
```

Comment: TIL. This should work, but I got `can't be blank and is invalid`

Comment: @Victor: you're right. It looks like `last_word_connector` is used for 3+ element arrays, and `two_words_connector` is for 2 element arrays. It's right there in the documentation, but I've never noticed that before! It should be possible to specify both arguments at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

[`String#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-prepend) **mutates** the string. That said, calls to it are not idempotent. Use the cloned version of `fields` array:

```
def error_message_for(field)
  field = field.map(&:dup) # HERE
  if field.present?
    if field.size > 1
      field.last.prepend("and/or ")
    end
    field.join(", ")
  end
end
```